# Multiple Knapsacks with splitting

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem, or-tools

I am trying to solve a problem that I believe is a variation of the [multiple knapsacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems).

Like the classical multiple knapsacks problem, I have a set of items, each one with a weight and a value and I am trying to divide them into multiple bins and find the combination with the best value.

But unlike the classical, I also need the following:

- Some bins might not accept some items, e.g.: I have item x and bins A, B, and C. Item x can only be added to the bins A and B.
- The item can be divided, an item with 100 could be divided into two so that it fits two bins of 50. Note: all numbers are integers.

My questions are:

## Is this a known problem?

It looks similar to the knapsack problem to me but does this variation have a name? If I knew the proper name for this problem I could search for solutions for it.

## Is it possible to solve with the solvers from OR-Tools?

I am using OR-Tools to explore this problem, but so far I haven't had any luck implementing this variation.

This is a not homework, my items are actually invoices that I am trying to assign to investment bins.

Comment: I believe this question is more suited for https://or.stackexchange.com/, that said, using a boolvar and an intvar for each (item, bin) pair, `boolbar => intvar > 0`, `not(boolvar) => intvar == 0` should be a good start

Comment: When you say an item can be divided...  are you saying that it is infinitely divisible in some way (like a real number) or just into integer components?  If infinitely divisible, I think this turns into an LP, right?

Comment: @JeffH I am working with integers only

Comment: Because the weights are divisible...  If the number of bins is reasonably large, the number of invoices is high, and if there are fairly limited restrictions, I think you could get a VERY good solution with a greedy algorithm that just packs in the high-value stuff and divides it out as necessary amongst the bins, avoiding prohibited ones, no?  Else, I think this is doable as an IP.

Comment: Can you split an order in more than 2 ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron Yes